# How do I pass 2 functions to touchableOpacity as props?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For example, I have `TouchableOpacity` component as a prop. When `TouchableOpacity` is pressed I want to call two functions. This is what I have

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressConfirm}>
 <Text>Yes</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

When `TouchableOpacity` is pressed I would like it to close the modal as well. How do I pass the `setModalVisible` as a prop with `onPressConfirm`. This is what I tried.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressConfirm, setModalVisible}>
 <Text>Yes</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

It does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Considering `TouchableOpacity` is your custom component.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressConfirm} visibilitySetter={setModalVisible} >
 <Text>Yes</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

If it is ReactNative's `TouchableOpacity`. Just pass one function and call two functions from that passed function.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
 <Text>Yes</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

const handlePress = () => {
   onPressConfirm()
   setModalVisible()
}
```

Comment: No, TouchableOpacity is not my custom component. It is being used in my custom component

Comment: I have given answer for that case too.

Answer (score 0):

In case `onPressConfirm` expects to get `setModalVisible` as argument:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>(onPressConfirm(setModalVisible))}>
 <Text>Yes</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: The OP hasn't shown the definition of `onPressConfirm`, how can you pass some function in its parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. You do this:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  style={styles.confirmationButtonContainer} 
  onPress={() => {onPressConfirm(); setModalVisible(!modalVisible);}}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my item component with touchable opacity and onPrress prop is being passed inside our touchable opacity as a callback:

```
const Item = ({title, id, OnPrress, backgroundColor, textColor}: ItemProps) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.item, {backgroundColor}]}
        onPress={()=>OnPrress(id,title)}
        >
        <Text style={[styles.title, {color: textColor}]}>{title}</Text>
        <Text>{id}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Now I'm passing this function inside this `onPrress` prop one is this:

```
function dataSetter (incoming: number,heading:string){
    const contains = sdata.some(i=>i.id === incoming)
// alternative i can do this setSelectedid(incoming) for my second fn
    if(contains){
      return
    }else{
      setSelectedData([
        ...sdata,
        {id: incoming, title: heading}
      ])
    }
  }
```

The other one is a setData function of `useState`.
So in my main app component where I need this component I am passing two functions like this:

```
return (
      <Item
        key={item.id}
        title={item.title}
        id={item.id}
        OnPrress={(id,title) => {dataSetter(id,title);
                   setSelectedId(item.id)
        }}
        backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
        textColor={color}
        />
        );
  }
```

So wherever you need to pass two functions as a prop the syntax will go like this:

```
<Component 
    propname = {(parameters)=>{function1(parameters);
                function2()
                 
}}
/>
```

If I go with alternate method, which is to setId inside the 1st function, then my onPrress will look like this:

```
OnPrress={dataSetter }
```